# Solving a polynomial equation involving gamma function

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to solve an equation having degenerate limit of Fermi-Dirac integral.

My code basically is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
FD1[d_, η_] := η^(d + 1)/
  Gamma[d + 2] ;  (* Defining the Fermi-Dirac integrals in degenerate *)

Solve[FD1[(d-2)/2, ηs] + FD1[(d-2)/2, ηs - vd] == 
  2 FD1[(d-2)/2, η0], {ηs}]
```

I want to solve for $\eta_S$ in terms of $\eta_0$ and $v_d$. Is it possible to solve it using this method? (And maybe expand the solution in terms of $vd$ as $vd$ is small and we can only pick the first few terms)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this. Your equation:

```
eqn = FD1[(d-2)/2, ηs] + FD1[(d-2)/2, ηs - vd] == 2 FD1[(d-2)/2, η0];
```

We need to find the zeroth order approximation of `ηs` when `vd` is small:

```
Simplify[Solve[eqn /. vd -> 0], (η0 | vd) ∈ Reals]
```

> {{ηs -> η0}}

Now, use [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
AsymptoticSolve[eqn, {ηs, η0}, {vd, 0, 5}]
```

> {{ηs -> 
>      vd/2 + ((-6 + d) (-2 + d) (-1 + d) vd^4)/(
>       1536 η0^3) + ((2 - d) vd^2)/(16 η0) + η0}}

**Addendum**

If you have an earlier version of Mathematica, so that you don't have access to [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve), you could try using the cloud instead. For example, define:

```
asymptoticSolve[args__] := CloudEvaluate[System`AsymptoticSolve[args]]
```

Then use `asymptoticSolve` instead of [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve).

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats really helpful. I don't have M12 so I cannot use AsymptoticSolve. Is there any other similar function in previous versions?

Comment: @Indeterminate What does `CloudEvaluate[$VersionNumber]` return for you?

Comment: It returns 12. But somehow, AsymptoticSolve doesn't work.

Comment: @Indeterminate See update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.